# HTML - Images not showing and Format is not the same as my Index.html

Tags: html

I'm having troubles loading the images and format of my another page, it is not showing. I create a folder(named pages) and put my page1.html file. When I click the button to redirect to my page1.html, the images are not showing and the format is not the same as my index.html file. But when I put the page1.html file on the same folder as my index.html, it is working fine and the format and images are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is the folder structure and the area in your code that links to your images.

You need to adjust the link to your images to the new folder structure like this:

**If in your index.html the structure is like this:**

```
<img src="/img/image.png" />
```

**Then in your pages folder that would be**

```
<img src="../img/image.png" />
```

The ".." indicates going back one folder.

In case you mean your stylesheet with the word "format" you need to apply the same technique in your

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet.css"></head>
```

The right path depends on your folder structure.

Comment: Uhhm, what should I do when i put it on like these pages/anotherpage/page1.html so a total of 2 folders, and when I used <img src="..../img/image.jpg"> is is not showing. How many "." should I used?

Comment: Oh, for that case you use the same technique but like this: ../../etc

Comment: Uhhm, what should I do because when I click the image logo of my another page, its not going back to home or index.html. Same goes for my  carousel in my other page, it is not moving.